# For loop range function

Tags: python, for-loop, range

When we execute the code

```
for i in range(10,0,-1):
    print('''          ''',i)
```

We get the result as 10 to 1(including 1)
But we do know that stop value is always n-1. So shouldn't it come until -1. Or does n-1 depend on the step value? Like if positive step value comes then n-1  and when negative step value comes n+2.

Comment: stop value is not `n-1` but it is `n-step`, and your `step=-1`, so stop value `= n - step = 0 - (-1) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

Stop value is not `n-1` but it is `n-step`, and your `step = -1`
So,

Stop value `= n - step = 0 - (-1) = 1`

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)

> `class range(start, stop[, step])`
>
> <snip>
>
> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and `r[i] < stop`.
>
> **For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and `r[i] > stop`.**

So, in case of `range(10,0,-1)` the return values all have to be bigger than `0`.